# Findroot: Maximum # of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a large fixed point problem (many equations and unknowns) using the findroot command. However, for very large problems (more than 300000 euqations), the FindRoot command is simply skipped (i.e., it does not even start to evaluate). I have enough memory in my PC (actually, the cutoff is identical for my (less sophisticated) laptop PC. Is there a limit the size of the fixed-point problem that FindRoot can handle?

Comment: 1st Q: has MMA kernel died? Restart MMA, evaluate your notebook and when it is "simply skipped" then without doing ANYTHING else click on Evaluation on the menu bar, slide mouse down to Quit Kernel, slide over to Local and see if that is greyed or still live and able to be clicked. Report back. 2nd Q: does evaluating the args to FindRoot fail. Replace FindRoot[{eqns},{vars}] with zed={{eqns},{vars}}; and stop, is the kernel is live? Report back. 3rd Q: zed=Norm[eqn1]+Norm[eqn2].. is the kernel live? 4th Q: repeat 3 in a Do 10^6 times with a RandomReal assigned to each var, is the kernel live?

Comment: Thanks a lot Bill, I will report back soon!